# Erro ao persistir objeto

Tags: jpa

Estou tentando persistindo um objeto e estou recebendo esse erro.
Alguém sabe como resolver? se precisar das classes, persistence.xml, eu envio.

não estou executando "on server" apenas pelo método main.

Não estou recebendo dados do servidor

código:

```
package br.com.casadocodigo.jsfjpa.persistence;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import br.com.casadocodigo.jsfjpa.entities.Automovel;

public class PersistidorDeAutomovel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("default");

        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        Automovel auto = new Automovel();
        auto.setAnoFabricacao(2014);
        auto.setMarca("Ferrari");
        auto.setModelo("La Ferrari");
        auto.setObservacoes("Nunca foi batido");

        EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();

        tx.begin();
        em.persist(auto);
        tx.commit();

        em.close();
        emf.close();
    }
}
```

> ago 04, 2016 6:12:10 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version
>    INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations
>   {4.0.2.Final} ago 04, 2016 6:12:10 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
>   INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.2.Final} ago 04, 2016 6:12:10 PM
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Environment  INFO: HHH000206:
>   hibernate.properties not found ago 04, 2016 6:12:10 PM
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider INFO: HHH000021:
>   Bytecode provider name : javassist ago 04, 2016 6:12:10 PM
>   org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   configure INFO: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool
>   (not for production use!) ago 04, 2016 6:12:10 PM
>   org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   configure INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 ago 04,
>   2016 6:12:10 PM
>   org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   configure INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: true ago 04, 2016 6:12:10
>   PM
>   org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   configure INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL
>   [jdbc:mysql://localhost/automoveis] ago 04, 2016 6:12:10 PM
>   org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   configure INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root,
>   password=****, autocommit=true, release_mode=auto} ago 04, 2016
>   6:12:12 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl
>   configure WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query
>   metadata : Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
>   ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server. ago 04,
>   2016 6:12:12 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect  INFO: HHH000400:
>   Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect ago 04, 2016
>   6:12:12 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder
>   useContextualLobCreation INFO: HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB
>   creation as connection was null ago 04, 2016 6:12:12 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator
>   initiateService INFO: HHH000268: Transaction strategy:
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory
>   ago 04, 2016 6:12:12 PM
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory  INFO:
>   HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory ago 04, 2016 6:12:13 PM
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version  INFO: HV000001:
>   Hibernate Validator 4.3.1.Final ago 04, 2016 6:12:15 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions WARN:
>   SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01 ago 04, 2016 6:12:15 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions ERROR:
>   Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
>   ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
>   Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open
>   connection    at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1310)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1397)
>     at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   br.com.casadocodigo.jsfjpa.persistence.PersistidorDeAutomovel.main(PersistidorDeAutomovel.java:26)
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not
>   open connection   at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:132)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:221)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:157)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1426)
>     at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:59)
>     ... 1 more Caused by:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
>   ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:344)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2332)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2369)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2153)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:792)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:47)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:381)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:204)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:292)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:214)
>     ... 6 more Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused:
>   connect   at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
>     at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
>     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.net.Socket.(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.net.Socket.(Unknown Source)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:257)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:294)  ... 21 more

Comment: Acho que seria interessante você inserir no enunciado da pergunta o seu código ...

Comment: envie seu persistence.xml, para melhor análise

Comment: De antemão, não vejo necessidade de fechar o "emf".
 emf.close();

Comment: Eu resolvi o problema, eu não tinha o pacote do MySQL instalado no pc. Obrigado pela ajuda